# How to use "Double Angle Formula"

Tags: trigonometry

So on my homework I am asked to find the $\cos A^\circ$.

The equation is: 
$$\cos^2(23^\circ)-\sin^2(23^\circ)=\cos A^\circ$$

I thought I could change the $\sin^2(23^\circ)$ to $1-\cos^2(23^\circ)$ and end up with this $$\cos^2(23^\circ)-1-\cos^2(23^\circ)=\cos A^\circ,$$ which would equal $-1$. However that is not correct and it has been a long while since I have done these so I could use a refresher.

Comment: you missed the negative sign when replacing: $\cos^2(23)-\sin^2(23) = \cos^2(23) - (1 - \cos^2(23)) = cos(A)$

Comment: I suggest you google "double angle formula" and see if something pops up that might be applicable.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the known identity the answer should be cos46 as cos2x=(cosx)^2-(sinx)^2